# web.api .net core не поднимает через самозавернный https сертификат

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

У меня есть VPS сервер. Там через IIS я поднял два сайта: клиент (vuejs) и сервер (web.api .net core). Клиент у меня поднялся без проблем на 80 порту. Сервер выдает следующую ошибку 500 Internal Server Error.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работоспособность самого приложения проверил через cmd dotnet [моя библиотека]. Все работает. БД создается, миграции применяются. Пытался найти решение, не получается.

Я думаю проблема в том, что web.api поднимается через https на 443 порту. Сертификата SSL у меня не было, для проверки работоспособности я создал через IIS самозавернный.

Клиент на vuejs обращается к серверу https://college-chesu-server.chesutime.ru. Мне кажется проблема именно в моем сертификате. Хотел понять можно ли вообще через самозаверенный сертификат поднимать приложения на .net core https. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: SSL сертификат можно добыть бесплатно - Let's Encrypt например. Но 500 ошибка не должна быть с этим связана. У сервера есть логи, читайте логи, там все сведения о том, что случилось.

Comment: Вот содержимое web.config. 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\CoreAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
Логи должны писаться, но они не пишутся. Все разрешения для папки есть.

Comment: Думаю, что в работе самого приложения ошибок нет, вот логи он и не пишет. Само приложение проверил через cmd dotnet. Никаких ошибок.

Comment: Ну так сделайте так, чтобы сервер писал логи. Любой http-сервер пишет логи доступа и ошибок, а ваш не пишет.